# What coordinates should I determine if I want to find the area of a surface determined by a double integral

Tags: integration, analysis, area, change-of-variable

I'm hoping I wrote the title correctly here.

I need to find out the area of the plain domain D, for which the frontier is
$\partial{D}: \begin{cases} y=x^2 \\ y=x \end{cases}$

I think it should be solved with the Green-Riemann equation , but I don't really know how.

Comment: You want to find the area between $y=x^2$ and $y=x$?

Comment: I think so. Don't know if translated to english it means the same. Basically I need to apply Green's formula to find the area. But how do I calculate my domain in that case?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at here: [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html]
Your domain is calculated by their intersection.
However, if it was me, I would calculate the area simply like this: $A=\int_{0}^1 (x^2-x)dx$

I hope this info is helpful for you.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar I have studied what you've sent me but I still didn't understand completely your point. Is there any chance you could show me or maybe explain it to me a little more detailed?